# Archive failed from shell Command line - LD error

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, cocoapods

Archive failed using shell command but gets successfully archived using Xcode. I'm using xcode 7.3 with cocoapods version 1.0.0, everything was working fine with same Xcode version but with CocoaPods 0.0.32 version.This issue is only for command line. It works fine for Xcode.

Command using for archiving(Internally this command is being used for archiving in Jenkins)

**/usr/bin/xcodebuild archive -archivePath ./build/CloudMessage -scheme LTDMessaging -workspace CloudMessage.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=./build 'CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Distribution: Leadership Team Dev, Inc' PROVISIONING_PROFILE=1d733147-864f-412e-8877-bcccc636ca27**

Here is the error i got

**Ld /Users/confiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CloudMessage-afevkkqtjcnmoddycvosdhbgoraa/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LTDMessaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/CloudMessage.build/Release-iphoneos/LTDMessaging.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LTD\ Messaging normal armv7**

Anyone know how to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Can you clear derived data once try again??...also LD error means its linker error, try to check if all the paths for the Header/Library search paths are set properly.

Comment: I'm done with both solutions but it didn't work.

Comment: Try again or google it...